# MYSQL get record which is recent before validate it status in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I'm having an issue getting the query results I would like.  I have tried to solve it for the past few hours and haven't been able to solve it.

**Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `whs_Lot_header` (
  `iLotheaderid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `iUniqueid` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `iImo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cWarehousecode` varchar(10) DEFAULT '',
  `cOriginmembercode` varchar(4) DEFAULT '',
  `cDestinationmembercode` varchar(4) DEFAULT '',
  `cCustomeralias` varchar(25) DEFAULT '',
  `cFilenumber` varchar(30) DEFAULT '',
  `cLotnumber` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `cHousebillofladingnumber` varchar(30) DEFAULT '',
  `cArrivalnoticenumber` varchar(30) DEFAULT '',
  `cCustomerreference` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `cForwarderreference` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `cShipperreference` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `cPlaceofreceipt` varchar(5) DEFAULT '',
  `cPortofloading` varchar(5) DEFAULT '',
  `cPortofdischarge` varchar(5) DEFAULT '',
  `cPlaceofdelivery` varchar(5) DEFAULT '',
  `tReceiveddate` date DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `cWarehousestatus` varchar(5) DEFAULT '',
  `tStatusdate` date DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `bStopoff` enum('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `cComments` varchar(2048) DEFAULT '',
  `cVessel` varchar(30) DEFAULT '',
  `cIntransitto` varchar(5) DEFAULT '',
  `cTransitport` varchar(5) DEFAULT '',
  `tETATransitPort` date DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `cIntransitfrom` varchar(5) DEFAULT '',
  `tEtaintransitfrom` date DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `bContainerloaded` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cLoadplanreference` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `cContainernumber` varchar(12) DEFAULT '',
  `cContainersealnumber` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `cLoadplancomments` varchar(2048) DEFAULT '',
  `cVoyage` varchar(10) DEFAULT '',
  `iStatus` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `iEnteredBy` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tEntered` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `iUpdatedBy` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tUpdated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`iLotheaderid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `whs_Lot_lineitem` (
  `iLotlineitemid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `iLotheaderid` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cCommodity` varchar(254) DEFAULT '',
  `iPieces` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cUom` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nWeight` float(8,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `nCube` float(15,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `cOverdimensionflag` enum('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `cOverheightflag` enum('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `cOverlengthflag` enum('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `cOverweightflag` enum('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `cOverwidthflag` enum('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `cHazardous` enum('N','Y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `iStatus` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `iEnteredBy` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tEntered` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `iUpdatedBy` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tUpdated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`iLotlineitemid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

**The Query**

```
SELECT whs_Lot_header.cLotnumber,
       whs_Lot_header.cCustomerreference,
       whs_Lot_header.cPlaceofdelivery,
       whs_Lot_header.cVessel, 
       whs_Lot_header.tReceiveddate,
       whs_Lot_header.cWarehousestatus,
       whs_Lot_lineitem.cHazardous,
       whs_Lot_lineitem.iPieces,
       whs_Lot_lineitem.nWeight,
       whs_Lot_lineitem.cCommodity,
       whs_Lot_lineitem.nCube
 FROM whs_Lot_header,whs_Lot_lineitem
WHERE whs_Lot_header.iLotheaderid = whs_Lot_lineitem.iLotheaderid
  AND whs_Lot_header.iStatus = 0
  AND whs_Lot_lineitem.iStatus = 0
  AND whs_Lot_header.cWarehousecode IN ('HAMW')
  AND whs_Lot_header.cWarehousestatus = 'B'
GROUP BY whs_Lot_header.cLotnumber,whs_Lot_lineitem.cCommodity
```

**The Problem** 
The `whs_Lot_header` table contains multiple records for a `cLotnumber` and I want to check the `cWarehousestatus` of the most recent record only.

**Basically I want to set a where clause priority, I want to check where record is recent after only should checking its status.**

It will really help me if someone could suggest a modification to the above query or new query for problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I may have accidentally overwrote an edit you made deleting a few lines of code.

Comment: Its ok. Thanks @Newd.

Answer (score 1):

Please see if the following query addresses your issue:

```
SELECT wlh.cLotnumber, wlh.cCustomerreference, wlh.cPlaceofdelivery, 
.....................
.....................
FROM whs_Lot_header wlh 

INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT iLotheaderid, cLotnumber, cCommodity, MAX(tEntered) FROM whs_Lot_header 
        GROUP BY cLotnumber, cCommodity
) temp 
    ON
wlh.iLotheaderid = temp.iLotheaderid
AND wlh.cCommodity = temp.cCommodity
AND wlh.cWarehousecode IN ('HAMW')
AND wlh.cWarehousestatus = 'B'

INNER JOIN whs_Lot_lineitem  wll
    ON wlh.iLotheaderid = wll.iLotheaderid
```

Please note that the `GROUP BY` clause in `temp` is based on the `GROUP BY` of the fields in the original question. Likewise, the conditions written in the given query are analogous to the conditions that could be written using an `INNER JOIN` here.

Comment: Thanks Dhruv for quick response why are you join whs_Lot_header and whs_Lot_lineitem, because i want to check whether tentered(datetime) is recent in whs_Lot_header  after only check its status(it also in whs_Lot_header ).

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap, I've revised the query now and also added a note. `tEntered` wasn't mentioned in the original query or the question, so I accidentally assumed that `MAX(cLotnumber)` could be used. However, the revised query should now take care of the most recent `tEntered` (for the **group** of `cLotnumber` and `cCommodity`). Using `JOIN` or cross product shouldn't ideally affect the results in this case as long as the conditions are checked in the correct order.

Comment: Like I said, `MAX` was based on the `GROUP BY` of the original query. The query `SELECT cLotnumber, cCommodity, MAX(tEntered) FROM whs_Lot_header 
        GROUP BY cLotnumber, cCommodity` is the most important component here. If the requirement is to have `MAX` for `cLotnumber` alone, then `cCommodity` should be removed from that query. Please would you mind running this query independently first and verifying if it then points to the recent most records as you like? Once that is done, it will easily fit well the other `JOIN`s.